# Use lock to avoid bank conflict in shared memory

Tags: cuda

I have an array `alpha` of size 32 located in shared memory, so it's very easy to create bank conflict. I think if I use lock when I access the `alpha` it will not result into bank confict, is that right ?

```
__shared__ int alpha[32];
bool lock = true;
while (lock) {
    if (0 == atomicCAS(mutex, 0, 1)) {
        int alpValue = alpha[indexalpha]; //indexalpha is computed
        if (alpValue > dist)
        {
            atomicExch(&alpha[indexalpha], dist);
        }
        atomicExch(mutex, 0);
        lock = false;
    }
}
```

PS: Can I use lock per block?

Comment: Shared memory is a per block resource, so your lock would have to be per block too. But I wouldn't recommend using locks in device code, its far too easy to mess up.

Comment: I believe that value of `indexalpha` and the way how you are computing it is the most important in order for us to help you, could you please provide this info?

Comment: a thread stores a string l-mer (lenght = 32) and
alpha stores number of characters in A different with strings l-mer in threads. 1 element in alpha is a position of character.
Example:
thread1: AAGTC
A: AAGTT  
alpha[5] += 1;
so on thread 2, 3, ..... 
So each thread i can access same the address in alpha.

Comment: On SM3.0-SM5.x a shared array of size 32 ints should never cause a bank conflict. On SM3.5 you will have to set 4B banks. I think the lock performance will be many times slower.

Comment: GregSmith Can you help me explain , share array will set into 32bank, and in each bank has many address, so if i have thread 1 access to address 1 of band 1, thread 10 access to address 2 of band 1, thread 1 and 10 in the same warp, is it bank conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Bank conflict are a shared memory addressing problem. The way the hardware deals with them is by **serializing** access to the same bank within a warp. Doing this by hand using a mutex/lock is not going to be better than the hardware solution, and can only be less efficient.

In case there is some misunderstanding here, I want to mention that bank conflicts do not automatically create a race condition. They are connected to hardware limitations, and as such only impact performance, not correctness.

The real solution to bank conflicts is to **reorganize your shared memory access patterns** to prevent them.